# How do I sync a calendar that I don't own with Evolution?

Tags: evolution, calendar

I follow Jupiter Broadcasting. In Google Calendar, I have their calendar added and I can view it with all of my other calendars. In Evolution, it only syncs the calendars that I created. How would I sync the Jupiter Broadcasting calendar in Evolution?

A link to the calendar is [here](https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&showNav=0&showCalendars=0&mode=AGENDA&height=540&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23ffffff&src=jalb5frk4cunnaedbfemuqbhv4@group.calendar.google.com&color=%235229A3&ctz=America/Chicago).

Comment: Simple. Add the web calendar in evolution. Open Evolution, go to `New->Calendar`, choose type as  `on the web`. Then copy/paste the calendar link in the `url` box. Change any other information you want to change. The calendar will appear in evolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [RSS](http://www.google.com/calendar/ical/jalb5frk4cunnaedbfemuqbhv4@group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics) link for the calendar from the [Jupiter Broadcasting website](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/release-calendar/). (It should have the `.ics` file extension at the end)

Create a new calendar `File` -> `New` -> `Calendar`

Select `On the Web` in the `Type` field and enter the calendar URL to the correct field.

[image: New Calendar Dialog]

[image: Screenshot of new Calendar in Action]

Answer (score 0):

Use the ICS link.
`New` -> `Calendar` -> `On The Web`, and use this as the URL:
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/jalb5frk4cunnaedbfemuqbhv4%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics